# Update Panel with fileupload control with images

Tags: c#, file-upload, updatepanel

I'm trying to make my application when I select item from dropdownlist and upload images it don't refresh the wholepage and just refresh the portion that update. The code shown below is working for the dropdownlist but not working for the upload button. When I upload image the page keep refresh. Do help me take a look on what did I wrongly or I forget to add anything. Thanks!

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPoliceID" runat="server"
            AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPoliceID_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Rank:"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload1" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload1_Click" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblUpload1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />

 </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlPoliceID" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload1" />
    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Hmm is it because your button btnUpload1 is a PostBackTrigger and not an AsyncPostBackTrigger? I believe it is code should look like <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload1" EventName="Click" />

Comment: I had tried that before, AsyncPostBackTrigger not working for Fileupload control.

Comment: You can add the code to upload behind the btnUpload1 control?

Comment: Quick search suggests the two controls UpdatePanel and FileUpload conflict with each other. You are better off perhaps coding this yourself, i.e. using System.Net.WebClient?

Answer (score 0):

Code here works bit in bold is what you want.

--Select--
                    --Foo--
                    --Bar--
                    --Goo--

```
    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Rank:"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload1" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload1_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblUpload1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <br />
 </ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlPoliceID" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    **<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload1" EventName="Click" />**
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```